Is it possible to bake the alpha-channel of holes from HP to LP?
I want to make a low-poly model of the truck and a cutout for windshield to make with the help of alpha texture instead of that-cut polygons in place of glass. Is it possible to somehow create a cutout using geometry on high-poly, bake this hole on alpha texture and apply this texture on low poly model to get a hole for the glass?
